# Request and Response Lifecyle in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very simple route setup for my web app,

```
router.get('/myTestRoute/:id', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    await doSomeAsync(req, res);
    res.json({ myObj: 32 });
    return next();
}
```

The doSomeAsync actually performs a request to a service and takes up to 20 seconds. However the response that the user is looking for doesn't need or care about the doSomeAsync response, so I thought I could remove the `await`, so that it would look like this:

```
router.get('/myTestRoute/:id', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    doSomeAsync(req, res);
    res.json({ myObj: 32 });
    return next();
}
```

Inside the doSomeAsync function, after the service call, we reference parameters on the req and res objects, like the parameters on the req object, and some authentication stuff on the res object.

I have found that this is not working, and I realized that I don't fully understand what happens with req and res after the response has been sent back to the user.

After I call `res.json()`, and then `next()`, what happens to the Request and Response objects, do they reset? Do they change in any way?

Should I refactor `doSomeAsync()` to accept the primitive values from `req.params`?

Comment: I guess that the response stays untouched. The response will definitely change after sending the response to the client. The stream to the client is closed and you can not send any data to it.

Comment: What exactly is doSomeAsync? If it's a side effect that doesn't affect the response, it shouldn't depend on req and res. Pass all relevant data as arguments. *Should I refactor doSomeAsync() to accept the primitive values from req.params?* - yes.

Comment: Thanks @estus I will do that, I'm still curious as to how req and res change after the response is sent back. This project I'm working on heavily modifies the req and res objects, which I'm not sure is a good practice, but regardless, knowing this behavior would be helpful.

Comment: This depends on middlewares that are involved in a request. They are able to change req and res. res is a wrapper around Node `http` res object. After you send a response you cannot modify a response but that's all, everything else is specific to your project.